# c++ correct use of delete after an assignment

Tags: c++

I'm a little bit confused on how to use correctly the delete keyword. Here is my scenario:

```
class Tuple {

public:

    Tuple(int columns);
    ~Tuple();

    void set(int i, string d);
    string get(int i);
    int columnCount();

private:

    string *data;
    int columns;

};


Tuple::Tuple(int columns) {

    this->columns = columns > 0 ? columns : 0;
    if (this->columns  > 0) {
        data = new string[this->columns];
    } else {
        data = 0;
    }

}

Tuple::~Tuple() {
    if (columns > 0) {
        delete[] data; 
    }
}

void Tuple::set(int i, string d) {

    if (columns > 0 && i > -1 && i < columns) {
        data[i] = d;
    }
}

class Table {

public:

    Table(int columns);
    ~Table();

    void insertTuple(Tuple t);
    Tuple getTuple(int i);

    int columnCount();
    int rowCount();

private:

    vector <Tuple> data;
    int columns;
    int rows;

};
```

Now, when I call the following code I get a segfault:

```
        Tuple *outTuple;
        outTuple = new Tuple(cCount);

        for (int i=0; i<cCount; i++) {
            tmpStr = string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)));
            outTuple->set(i, tmpStr);
        }
        (*outTable)->insertTuple(*outTuple);

        delete outTuple; //here I get segfault
```

What is wrong with my code? Is my code not well written? Can I improve it and avoid segfault?

Comment: Where is the definition of `Tuple::Tuple(in columns)`? Are you actually allocating space for `data`?

Comment: added constructor and deconstructor to question

Comment: Also, why not use std::vector instead of pointer for data ? This would free you of all the pointer trouble ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the `Tuple` violates [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29). Specifically, you need to define a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator. Otherwise you are probably double-deleting `data`.

You don't show the constructor and the destructor, but memory management practices employed by `Tuple` look fragile. Why not use `std::vector` instead of a pointer?

Comment: thank you very much! I added constructor and deconstructor to question

Comment: @the_candyman: and what about the copy constructor? That's really important.

Comment: @GregHewgill I did not defined it. Some suggestion about what it should do?

Comment: @the_candyman: The copy constructor should *copy* the data pointed to by `data`, rather than having two `Tuple` objects pointing to the same underlying data (which is the behaviour of the default copy constructor as supplied by the compiler).

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically memory allocated variables with pointers, usually have a "container" or "owner".

In this case, the function is the main "container".

"Containtment" or "Ownership" may be transfer, example, from function to other variable, in this case, maybe "outTable".

Does the "outTable" deletes the tuple from memory ?

Are you intended to let "outTable" become the container of the tuple, and let it drop the tuple from memory, instead of the function ?

OR, do you intend that "outTable", only references the tuple, and, let the function drop the tuple from memory.

Cheers.